# docker-compose not showing any changes to code

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working on a project that uses `docker-compose up` to start up and run. I am not very familiar with docker-compose and I couldn't really find an answer in the docs. According to the docs the `up` command rebuilds the container from the docker file, however this does not seem to happen.

When I try to add `print` commands for debugging nothing happens. The program already throws a few print commands and I tried changing those to be sure, and they always print the same. Do I have to add something to the `up` command to make the container rebuild?

docker-compose/yml:

```
dockbrato:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - "/sys:/sys"
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

Comment: Can you shows us your `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: I added the file to the question

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `docker-compose up` only builds images that don't exist already; it will not rebuild an image whose source has changed.  If you want to rebuild your image, run `docker-compose build` before `docker-compose up`.

Comment: but  `volumes` means to mount that to the docker container, so I shouldn't have to rebuild? [This article even says that it should show live changes](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2015/03/17/docker-rails-docker-compose-together-in-your-development-workflow/). I'm curious to know why it is not working. My boss does it to have data be consistent when running databases through docker. And the volumes change live.

Comment: docker-compse up --build would combine both

Comment: why this answer is placed bottom to me.... upvote!

Comment: Change sorting!

Answer (score 28):

To force the image to be rebuilt after a change in the source, use the `--build` flag:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

will rebuild all layers after the layer with the changes. For layers before the change, docker uses the cache versions.

This avoids having to use two separate commands as per @jwodder's answer.

Comment: Assuming one has a service that relies on the container, does the service go down during the rebuild process? By service, I mean a web API.

Answer (score 14):

You can use

```
$ docker-compose build --no-cache
$ docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

taken from
https://vsupalov.com/docker-compose-runs-old-containers/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Docker version 1.3 and Docker Compose version 1.22 on CentOS 7. I could resolve the problem by upgrading to Docker version 18.06. To do this, I took the following steps. First, I removed the old version of Docker by running the following command:

```
sudo yum remove docker \
                  docker-client \
                  docker-client-latest \
                  docker-common \
                  docker-latest \
                  docker-latest-logrotate \
                  docker-logrotate \
                  docker-selinux \
                  docker-engine-selinux \
                  docker-engine \
```

Then, I set up required repositories:

```
sudo yum install -y yum-utils \
    device-mapper-persistent-data \
    lvm2
sudo yum-config-manager \
    --add-repo \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

and finally installed the latest CE version:

```
sudo yum install docker-ce
```

After upgrading Docker, I removed containers built based on the old version of Docker by running this command:

```
sudo docker container rm -f -v my_container_1 my_container_2
```

Running `docker-compose up` rebuilt the containers. Afterward, changing the code was successfully reflected in the desired container.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like many people don't get the difference between ADD/COPY during build and changes to a mounted volume. If changes in a mounted volume seem to stop syncing I stop the container and restart it using:

```
docker-compose stop <container>
docker-compose up -Vd <container>
```

which recreates volumes instead of reloading them

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to run `docker-compose up --build` each time if we want our changes to be applied. Using volume, we can set a bind between our dev directory (where changes were made) and dir inside a docker container.

**Example:**
In my file system, the working dir for my project is `/home/user/frontend`, and inside the container is `home/node/app`. All I need to do is set a proper mapping like this:

```
volumes:
  - /home/user/frontend:/home/node/app
```

Docker will pick up changes from your working dir dynamically.

(windows users should use wsl with some disto to make it work)