# How can I see changes in c# application running on Docker container?

Tags: c#, docker

I have ASP.NET MVC application in .NET Core. I run it in Docker using docker-compose.yml and command:

```
docker-compose up –d
```

Now I can display my website on http://localhost:5000.
But if I change something in class or cshtml file I don't see those changes on http://localhost:5000. What should I do? Stop container and what next? Or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker-compose not showing any changes to code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750386/docker-compose-not-showing-any-changes-to-code)

Answer (score 0):

You should rebuild your container

```
docker-compose up –d --build
```

You can rebuild specific containers in docker-compose like this

```
docker-compose up –d --build service_name_1 service_name_2
```

from this source https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/

```
docker-compose build
Estimated reading time: 1 minute

Usage: build [options] [--build-arg key=val...] [SERVICE...]

Options:
    --compress              Compress the build context using gzip.
    --force-rm              Always remove intermediate containers.
    --no-cache              Do not use cache when building the image.
    --pull                  Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image.
    -m, --memory MEM        Sets memory limit for the build container.
    --build-arg key=val     Set build-time variables for services.
    --parallel              Build images in parallel.

Services are built once and then tagged, by default as project_service. For example, composetest_db. If the Compose file specifies an image name, the image is tagged with that name, substituting any variables beforehand. See variable substitution.

If you change a service’s Dockerfile or the contents of its build directory, run docker-compose build to rebuild it.
```